# Maui google play console: The label for this item may not be readable by a screen reader

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-play, maui

For my application I have some warning in google play console: The label for this item may not be readable by a screen reader. Mainly for my Image buttons, but also for Slider.

[image]

The solution suggested by google play console is to add content label.
I added for example this to my Slider:

```
SemanticProperties.Description="Adjust the volume" SemanticProperties.Hint="Adjust the volume"
```

But it still show this warning. I also tried to change the background color for better contrast, but it didn't help.

What is solution for this in Maui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case setting the property for the control in xaml:

```
SemanticProperties.Description="" AutomationProperties.HelpText="" AutomationId=""
```

or

```
SemanticProperties.Description="" AutomationProperties.Name="" AutomationId=""
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [goolge's official document about the Content labels](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690?hl=en). You may need to use the native code to set the control's contentDescription. Such as:

In the page.xaml:

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.TestPage"
             Title="TestPage">
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="0"/>
</ContentPage>
```

In the page.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
#if ANDROID
   base.OnHandlerChanged();
   (slider.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Widget.SeekBar).ContentDescription = "this is slider";
#endif
}
```

And for the imagebutton, you can use the same way as above.